# Issues in loading flat file delimited by || into SQL Server database through SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, exception, ssis

I have a file containing almost 1 million records and I have created a SSIS package to load the data into a SQL Server database. While executing the package, there are some records which are failing to get inserted and being written in the error file along with the error code.

> Error code - 1071607675- Invalid Character in Flat File or Truncate problem

I tried inserting those records again by copying them in another file and running through the same SSIS and records got inserted without any error.

I am not able to understand what exactly is the issue with those records.
Since the dataset is huge I am not able to share here.

Let me know if anyone can help me in identifying the issue.

Comment: Can you share few records with us (few inserted in first try and few not inserted...)? Can you share the create table statement with us also.

Comment: My guess is that somewhere earlier in the file the delimiters got "off" and when it finally got bad enough to error out, the reported line is well past the source bad line. Often, your staging table will look like a barber pole (assuming it's just n/varchar fields) if you order by insert time. You can turn down the maximum row buffer size to 1 and set the ole db command to also have a commit size of 1. Inefficient as can be, but as only 1 row is allowed in the buffer, it makes it obvious which row is "bad"

Comment: One possibility is that the original source file contained mixed EOL (end of line) sequences, e.g.: SSIS was configured for and expected each line to end with carriage return, linefeed (0x0d 0x0a), but some lines only ended with either a carriage return (0x0d) or a linefeed (0x0a). Depending on the text editor you used to extract the failed records and insert them into a new file those line endings could have been corrected (0x0d 0x0a) and so read in successfully.

Comment: @billinkc I tried as per your suggestion but got the same error file as before with the same records.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning is there any way to rectify it. I tried changing EOL, but I am getting the same result.

Comment: If you've changed the EOL characters in the original file using an editor capable of doing that (e.g.: jEdit, Visual Studio Code, etc.) and it hasn't changed the outcome then it's probably some other encoding issue in the file. Possibly the lines before the lines reporting errors are missing EOL characters, or they aren't quoting field values correctly (e.g.: in an improperly constructed Quoted CSV file they might have a start quote but no finishing quote on some fields).

Answer (score 0):

Cause could be

- additional pipe delimiter in the data row
- based on the flat file encoding UTF there might be a special character that you package is not able to recognized (if dtsx was initially designed to load data from ANSI encoded file)